# Variants of travelling salesman problem: must visit each ``type'' of city for at least once.

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Suppose I have a directed graph, where it begins with a start node and ends with a end node. For each intermedia node, it has a type. There are directed edges defined in the nodes (not between every node pairs) with different distances. My problem is: how to find out a shortest path which ``passes each type of node for at least once''? Is it a well-known problem, or any kind of variants of travelling salesman problem?

Comment: You could formulate it as an integer program but I don't know that this is a particularly well-studied problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, could you help to provide more details about how to solve it by considering it as an integer program? Shall I formulate it in some specific format and solve it by some existing solvers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This variant is known as the [Set TSP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_TSP_problem), as well as several other names mentioned in the link.

The first reference (Noon and Bean, 1993) describes a transformation in which each set/type is visited exactly once but mentions that Noon's dissertation [10] shows how to handle intraset arcs.

Comment: Yeah, I also realized this problem and read it in Wiki. One problem I am not sure is: does Set TSP require ``visit each set at least once'' or require ``visit each set only once''? Because maybe for each path we found, there are always two nodes belong to the same set are visited.

Comment: At least once.  In fact, one of the problem transformations involves solving a TSP on the original node set, with zero-cost edges between nodes of the same type.  In that case, every node is visited.

Comment: Actually in my case, the distance between different nodes in the same group cannot set to be zero.  Let's say we have "->A1->B->A2->C->" in our path, then the distance between A1 and A2 is dist(A1, B) + dist (B, A2)

Comment: Those extra nodes are not necessarily visited in the final subtour.  The zero costs are just a modeling transformation to be able to call a standard TSP solver to solve the original problem.